# Как создать распространяемый пакет с приложением django?

Tags: python, django

У меня есть django-приложение. Мне необходимо сделать следующее:

- Создать и описать файл setup.py для сборки пакета и распространения.
- Описать файл таким образом, чтобы в собранном пакете среди python файлов, находились только скомпилированные файлы *.pyc

Может кто-нибудь объяснить, как это сделать? Заранее спасибо